# I want to create a column with delimited values

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have Vin column and a Image_url column.

I have 5 image_url's for each vin.

I want to reduce it to 1 row per vin with all the image_url's for 1 vin in a delimited field

Vin     URL
12345   url1|url2|url3|url4|url5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to aggregate values into a delimited string, I would recommend using Snowflake's [LISTAGG()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/listagg.html) function. Here is a trivial example:

```
WITH CTE_VIN_URLS AS (
  SELECT $1 AS VIN
        ,$2 AS URL
    FROM VALUES
           (12345, 'url1')
          ,(12345, 'url3')
          ,(12345, 'url5')
          ,(12345, 'url2')
          ,(12345, 'url4')
          ,(23456, 'url7')
          ,(23456, 'url8')
          ,(23456, 'url6')
)
SELECT VIN
      ,LISTAGG(URL, '|') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY URL) AS URLS
  FROM CTE_VIN_URLS
 GROUP BY VIN
 ORDER BY VIN
;
```

Note that I have intentionally presented the values in unsorted order to highlight the use of the optional `WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ...)` clause.

That said, I would consider replacing the delimited string with an ARRAY (which is natively supported as a first class data type in Snowflake). In that case, I would use Snowflake's [ARRAY_AGG()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_agg.html) function:

```
WITH CTE_VIN_URLS AS (
  SELECT $1 AS VIN
        ,$2 AS URL
    FROM VALUES
           (12345, 'url1')
          ,(12345, 'url3')
          ,(12345, 'url5')
          ,(12345, 'url2')
          ,(12345, 'url4')
          ,(23456, 'url7')
          ,(23456, 'url8')
          ,(23456, 'url6')
)
SELECT VIN
      ,ARRAY_AGG(URL) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY URL) AS URLS
  FROM CTE_VIN_URLS
 GROUP BY VIN
 ORDER BY VIN
;
```